# How can I make a DataGridView not to produce a new row whenever any of the cell in the preceeding row is filled up?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

I just want to make the DataGridView to have a new row after filling up the last cell. Do any of the DataGridview properties have this settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `AllowUserToAddRows` property to false

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```